# MySQL error 2003

Tags: mysql, port

I have PC with MySQL running on it (on localhost), there is also Java App, that uses db and connects to MySQL without problem, but when I try to connect via command line(cmd) I get this message: "ERROR 2003: can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)".

I think that this is some kind of port/firewall problem, but I don’t have any knowledge in this particular area.
I have similar problems with other programs running on this PC, too – IE (Cannot open pages), Java Web Start (get Socket Exception) ... BTW the crash happened after uninstall process of NOD32.

I certainly could use some peace of advice, because it’s really import to dump the data base.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention - its Windows XP

Answer (score 0):

First things to try:

1) Can you ping the localhost?

```
C:\> ping localhost
Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=128
...
```

2) If that fails can you ping 127.0.0.1?

```
C:\> ping 127.0.0.1
Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=128
...
```

3) Can you connect to MySQL using the IP address 127.0.0.1?

4) Can you browse to local website using the IP address 127.0.0.1?